# Check if the new element has been added to the table in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner, angular-promise

In my Angular app I have a table (ng-grid to be precise) and I have a procedure to add the a new element to it. I spare you the details, but the procedure is multi-step, involves talking to the server and results in a new item in the ng-grid table. I know the name of the new item and I want to check in my protractor test that this item has indeed be added. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
 var nameTestItem="mySuperItem";
 //... some actions to add the element, and going back to the page with the table 
 browser.get('#/resTable');

//checking if there is new item with this title
var element_added=false;
//picking the cell of the table with css selector and searching for the text
element.all(by.css('div.ui-grid-cell-contents')).then(function(elements) {
    _.forEach(elements, function(el) {
        el.getText().then(function(text){
            console.log(text);
            element_added= element_added || (nameTestItem==text);
        });
    });
});
browser.sleep(1000);

browser.pause();
expect(element_added).toBeTruthy();
```

apparently my problem  is that I'm dealing with a lot of promises. How would you tackle this problem? I really don't want to rely on `count()` because I don't want collisions when several people execute the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) instead:

```
var results = element.all(by.css('div.ui-grid-cell-contents')).filter(function(elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function(text) {
        return nameTestItem === text;
    });
});
expect(results.count()).toEqual(1);
```

And, if you are using [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers), a bit more readable way:

```
expect(results).toBeNonEmptyArray();
```